# Programming Java GUI with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, components, runtime-error, installation-package

Everyone
I recently installed java JDK. However, I am not able to program GUI applications.
For instance when i want to program anything from "swing" components i cannot include Buttons, Labels, Text, etc.

As a developing tool I am using Eclipse.

Can someone tell me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 8):

Eclipse doesn't come with default UI editing tools. You have to install extra plugins to get that sort of UI. [Eclipse WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) is the best plugin I find to create a Swing UI.

Comment: Some of the Eclipse packages *do* come with Window Builder installed. For Luna (the latest release as 2014), The "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" package and the "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers" packages already include WindowBuilder.

Comment: I've never used that build. I have Eclipse Kepler which doesn't have this package.

Comment: The Kepler "IDE for Java Developers" package *does* include WindowBuilder. Perhaps you downloaded the "IDE for Java EE Developers" or the "Eclipse Standard" package, those do not include WindowBuilder by default. You have to pay attention to which package you download, as each of them includes different features to cater to its intended user.

Comment: I have the "IDE for Java Developers" from a couple years ago and it didn't come with WindowBuilder. May be it wasn't in it back then?

Answer (score 1):

Use [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) which has the best GUI tool.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if your problem is same as the one I got. If your error shows "Access Restriction: The  type is not accessible due to restriction on library" then you have to **Right click your project-> Properties-> Java build path -> Libraries -> Remove the JRE System Library-> Click add library-> add back the JRE system library**, then the error will goes off.